# How to monitor a file's last modification date and rename it accordingly?

Tags: file, unix, webcam

I have a webcam that works by re-uploading the same file and overwriting itself every 10 seconds. I'd like to create a shell script that monitors this file (camFile.jpg) and when it detects it's been overwritten, it duplicates it and creates a new file called camFile-TIMESTAMP.jpg. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533923/monitor-folder-for-new-files-using-unix-ksh-shell-script-or-perl-script-and-trig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be best served by using inotify. But it depends on which language you're using.

http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

Comment: Would this be possible in PHP?

Comment: Did more searching and this thread seems to be the most helpful. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533923/monitor-folder-for-new-files-using-unix-ksh-shell-script-or-perl-script-and-trig